# Stopping Intermarriage

Tags: intermarriage

Intermarriage is the reason that a significant number of Jews are disappearing. What can or should be said to someone who is contemplating marrying out of the Jewish faith?

Comment: That sounds very broad. Wouldn't it depend a great deal on the particular people involved?

Comment: Indeed, this is a topic that Rabbi's have built their careers around. From the FAQ: 
            "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an _entire book_ that 
            answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: Here is a good answer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nY1xOKpcmw

Comment: Well I am looking for a few quick pointers when you meet or know a fellow who is contemplating intermarriage.

Comment: @GershonGold Speak frankly with them, and from the heart. Anything else won't be effective since they are being motivated by the heart in the first place.

Comment: Source for your first statement?